# apply paragraph style to paragraphs containing a specific font in MS Word

Tags: microsoft-word

I have a Word document with paragraphs in different fonts. Some of the paragraphs are for code listings and they are in Courier New font only. Other paragraphs have mixed fonts. It's a large file. I wonder if there is a way to change the style OF THOSE PARAGRAPHS CONTAINING ONLY COURIER FONTS, i.e., the code listing paragraphs, and leave other paragraphs alone. I have defined a new style but changing the styles of those paragraphs by hand is too time consuming.

I got this file from somebody else, and it was not created with different styles. All the paragraphs (code listing and other text) currently have the style named "Normal". And some words in the non-code-listing paragraphs are also in Courier New font.

Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

[Yes](http://www.codejacked.com/quick-tip-using-ms-words-search-replace-on-formatting/).

1. Go to Find and Replace.
2. Click more. Click on the Find input box, then click on the Format button on the bottom left. You should see options.
3. Enter Courier as the font under Font. Then do the same with your desired formatting in Replace (probably under Paragraph). Bam.